# A has 10 coins while B has 6 coins

Tags: probability

A has 10 coins while B has 6 coins, what is the probability that A will have more heads than B?

---

If they had both 6 coins then the probability would be $0.5$, But A has 4 more coins which is an advantage in getting more heads. So I thought, what is the probability of getting at least 1 head in those 4 coins?

P(at least 1 in 4) = 1- p(no heads) =

$P=1-\binom{4}{0}0.5^4 = 0.9375$

So I would say that A has $93.75\%$ chance of getting more heads than B

Comment: By your logic if A has 2 coins and B has 1 then you have $50\%$ getting more heads.

Comment: yes, that's the logic. So you should calculate the probability of getting a head in the k coins you have more. but I am not sure! @OğuzhanKılıç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no easy computation to be done by hand, here is an approach that tries to reduce the computation (even though it is all by an online calculator in any case). There are three cases to consider -

a) $A$ has more heads and tails than $B$
b) $B$ has more tails or equal (then $A$ surely has more heads)
c) $B$ has more heads or equal

So we either find $(a) + (b)$ or we find $(c)$ and subtract from $(1)$. If $i$ is the number of heads that $B$ gets then the below expression gives $(c)$, which is the number of outcomes where $A$ gets less number of heads than $B$ or equal.

$ \displaystyle \small \sum \limits_{i=0}^6 {6 \choose i} \sum \limits_{j=0}^i{10 \choose j} = 14893$

So the desired probability is,

$ \displaystyle \small 1 - \frac{14893}{2^{16}} = \frac{50643}{65536} \approx 0.77275$

Answer (score 2):

I calculated the same probability as David G. Stork, in the following way:

Flipping coins is a binomial experiment. For the 6-coin person, I calculated the probability of $n$ heads for $0\leq n \leq6$ and for the 10-coin person I calculated the probability of $n$ heads for $0\leq n \leq10$.

Then I made an array of all possible outcomes and multiplied the probabilities together (because they are independent).

[image]

Highlighted in yellow are the outcomes in which the person with $10$ coins has strictly more heads than the person with $6$ coins. The sum of those cells is the overall probability of approximately $0.77$.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this analytically using Bayes rule. So, the first step is: conditional on B getting $0\le n_b \le 6$ heads, what is the probability that A will get more heads (i.e., $n_b<n_a\le 10$)? From the binomial distribution, this will be
$$\sum_{n_a=n_b+1}^{10}\binom{10}{n_a}\frac{1}{2}^{10}$$

Then you multiply this by the probabilities of $B$ getting $n_b$ heads:
$$\sum_{n_b = 0}^6\left[\sum_{n_a=n_b+1}^{10}\binom{10}{n_a}\frac{1}{2}^{10}\right]\binom{6}{n_b}\frac{1}{2}^6$$

This expression can be easily computed in Python with SciPy:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
P = sum(binom.pmf(k=nb, n=6, p=0.5)*sum(
                    binom.pmf(k=na, n=10, p=0.5) for na in range(nb+1, 11)
                        )
       for nb in range(7))
```

giving the outpyt `P = 0.7727508544921884`. This seems in line with the result from @David G. Stork, but slightly more precise.

To confirm this, we can perform Monte Carlo simulations. I run 1 million simulations of the process below:

```
import numpy as np
def iteration():
    # Heads = 1, Tails = 0
    A = np.random.randint(0, 2, size = 10)
    B = np.random.randint(0, 2, size = 6)
    if np.sum(A)>np.sum(B):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
numerical_prob = np.mean([iteration() for i in range(1000000)])
```

And the output gives `numerical_prob = 0.772503`, pretty close to the analytical result.

Answer (score 0):

I find the probability to be 0.772751.

[image]

Write out the binomial distributions and sum over the cases where one is greater than the other.

Comment: Could you explain the approach?